# How to use _extra dynamically in smarty {html_select_time}

Tags: php, html, smarty

I have a problem here. I can add extra value like `hour_extra='id="hour_id"'` in `{html_select_time}`. But I want to add this dynamically. How to do this? Please help

My Code is below.

```
{section name=foo start=2 loop=18 step=1}
    {assign var="itt" value=$smarty.section.foo.index}
       {html_select_time prefix=pre$itt use_24_hours=false display_seconds=false minute_interval=5 time="00:00" hour_extra='id="$itt"' }
{section}
```

here it is not working.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you need:

```
{section name=foo start=2 loop=18 step=1}
    {assign var="itt" value=$smarty.section.foo.index}
        {html_select_time prefix="pre{$itt}" use_24_hours=false display_seconds=false minute_interval=5 time="00:00" hour_extra="id='{$itt}'" }
{/section}
```

(tested in Smarty 3.1.18)

Comment: Ok thanks. It is working. But I am working with a old project with Smarty 2. So in between curly B is not required. So for smarty 2, hour_extra="id='$ehh'" is ok.

Comment: So if possible mark this answer as accepted to let other users know they don't have to reply because you already have working solution and in future users who have same problem to know there is solution